# How to set 'html' email template for webform email setting?

Tags: webforms, emails

Is there any way to use html email for e-mail template in webform email setting?

In my webform node I go to: node/113/webform/emails/1 to change the setting but I don't see any 'html' option. Look my capture:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) will give you that option.  It integrates with [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform). To use HTML Mail you will also need [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem).

Go to Configuration > Mail System and set the Site wide Default to be HTML Mail and the HTML Mail module to be HTML Mail.

And if the option "Send e-mail as HTML" does not appear while editing a Webform email. Go to: `admin/config/content/webform` **check** "HTML mail system".

Comment: I just enable both module, but I see no option for html with webform yet. What else do I need to do?

Comment: You can actually set HTML Mail to be the default Mail option, and then webform can continue sending to the default.  Go to Configuration > Mail System, and set the Site wide Default to be HTMl Mail and the HTML Mail module to be HTML Mail

Comment: done. It is partially working though. the <b> tag is replace by '*' character.

Comment: I enable http://drupal.org/project/mimemail and now it working fine.

Answer (score 7):

If the option "Send e-mail as HTML" does not appear while editing a Webform email, visit admin/config/content/webform and select *HTML mail system*.

This was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module which I have used in the past. It allows you to have a html mail option per webform email configuration. 
This also needs the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) Module