# Confirmation Email from Webform Submission

Tags: webforms, emails

How would I send a confirmation email to the email address entered in a Contact Us form created with the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module?

Comment: I would try Rules but I don't know off the top of my head how exactly.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is available out of the box with Webform.

1. On the webform node page, click on the "Webform" tab
2. From the webform tab, click on the "E-mails" tab
3. Click on the "Component value" radio button and select the component of the webform that captures the email address.
4. Click on the "Add" button
5. On the next page, you can set the Subject, From Address, From Name, and E-mail contents.

Comment: This is just sending an email to the user not actually a confirmation email, which I would assume would ask the user to click a link for the submission to be valid.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption. At any rate, a module exists for that if that's what you're looking for: [Webform Confirm Email Address](https://drupal.org/project/webform_confirm_email) and/or [Email campaign](https://drupal.org/project/form_email_confirmation).

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks for the help but it seems webform confirm email address isn't what I am looking for. It is only delaying emails until the email address is validated not marking the submission itself as valid.

Comment: You should post this as a new question. I don't think it's been definitively covered here. Essentially, it sounds like you're looking for Webform submissions to have two states: Verified and Unverified. In your case, submissions are verified by proving you have access to the email address you entered on the form.

Comment: Adam Balsam ok useful but how to send this email in html (Im ignoring the comments above)

Comment: @SsouLlesS see [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29461/how-to-set-html-email-template-for-webform-email-setting).

Answer (score 1):

Step1:  On the webform node page, click on the "Webform" tab

Step2:  Click on the "E-mails" tab

Step3:  Click on the "Component value" radio button and select the component of the webform select the  email address component (the field the submitter will use to add his email address.

Step4: Select custom under E-mail subject and in the custom field write thank you for your submission.

Step5: Select custom under E-mail from address and use appropriate email like info@mywebsite.com

Step6: Step5: Select custom under E-mail from name and use appropriate name like the name of the company or website

Now select  custom template under E-mail template and in field below  add your message like

Thank you for submitting your message. You will be contacted should a suitable asap.
Please do not respond to this email as this is an automated response.

Step:7 Click on the save button

Answer (score 0):

There is a module available for this purpose; [Webform Confirm Email Address](https://drupal.org/project/webform_confirm_email)

> webform_confirm_email is a simple addon module for the webform module.
>
> If you define an email in webform (eg. mydomain.net/node/9999/webform/emails) this email/these emails will be send immediately when the user clicked the webform submit button.

*Even without this module, we can send confirmation email to users. Important thing to note here is while creating the email component, we have to select **Email as webform's Type**. Go to the Email section of the webform. From there you can select the the email component as 'to'. Then add from, subject and template of the email to be sent.*