# webform email font formatting

Tags: webforms, emails

How do you bold the output of the value within the email text? When an email is sent to the submitter I would like to bold a value that is input from the webform.

Comment: what drupal email modules and what webform email templates have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29461/how-to-set-html-email-template-for-webform-email-setting

Comment: Just the default with drupal 7